# How to use system() function in c++ to open apps

Tags: c++

I want to know how to use system() function in c++ to open any application, like vlc, notepad or google chrome, ect. Please anyone help me in this.

Comment: Windows also has `ShellExecute`

Answer (score 2):

You put the command that you'd normally type at the Command Line as the first argument:

```
system("dir");
```

..and it'll do 'dir' on the current working directory. The return code is the exit code of the program that you ran. If you're launching a GUI application, the return code is usually going to be zero meaning that it launched. Otherwise, look up the return code in the manual page/documentation for the command you're using.

Putting the entire path to the program you want to run will help with any environment issues.

This mechanism gives you very little control, but it is somewhat cross-platform. If you're on Windows and you want more fine-grained control, there are alternatives such as [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or  [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For more information, see the documentation:

C++ (platform independent) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Windows : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/277bwbdz.aspx

Linux: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system